# Best way to find min value in array of objects and also return the other property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an object of `students` & I'd like to get the name of the youngest student.

```
const students = [
  { name: 'Hans', age: 3 },
  { name: 'Ani', age: 7 },
  { name: 'Budi', age: 10 },
  { name: 'Lee', age: 13 }
 ]
```

I get the youngest age by this

```
function getYoungestAge(data) {
   return resultMin = data.reduce((min, p) => p.age < min ? p.age : min, data[0].age)
}

getYoungestAge(students) // return 3
```

How can I return not only age but also name ? `// example: 3 and Hans`

Comment: what if you have more than one?

Comment: `data.reduce((min, p) => p.age < min.age ? p : min, data[0])`

Comment: @dfsq you can even remove `, data[0])` as this will be passed by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always take the whole object through your `reduce` and not just the age

```js
const students = [
  { name: 'Hans', age: 3 },
  { name: 'Ani', age: 7 },
  { name: 'Budi', age: 10 },
  { name: 'Lee', age: 13 }
 ]

function getYoungestAge(data) {
   return data.reduce((min, p) => p.age < min.age ? p : min, data[0])
}

var youngest = getYoungestAge(students) 
console.log(youngest);
```

Another way would be to sort the list and take the first. NOTE: This way changes the original array. That is fine in some cases and undesirable in others. I                 prefer the first way above in most cases.

```js
const students = [
  { name: 'Hans', age: 3 },
  { name: 'Ani', age: 7 },
  { name: 'Budi', age: 10 },
  { name: 'Lee', age: 13 }
 ]

function getYoungestAge(data) {
   data.sort( (x,y) => x.age-y.age);
   return data[0];
}

var youngest = getYoungestAge(students) 
console.log(youngest);
```

Also note that *both* of these solutions return the first item with the lowest age where more than 1 student shares the same age.

Comment: **Note:** Sort will mutate original array. If this is not required, use first approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could return an array with the filtered objects. This works with a single loop and if some people have the same mininmum age, then all peoples with that age are returned.

```js
function getYoungestAge(data) {
    return data.reduce(function (r, o, i) {
        if (!i || o.age < r[0].age) {
            return [o];
        }
        if (o.age === r[0].age) {
            r.push(o)
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

const students = [{ name: 'Hans', age: 3 }, { name: 'Ani', age: 7 }, { name: 'Budi', age: 10 }, { name: 'Lee', age: 13 }]

console.log(getYoungestAge(students));
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the array to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), with the age as `key`, and the value an array of all the students with that age. To get the youngest, find the [min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) of the the map's keys, and [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) the value of that key from the map:

```js
const students = [{"name":"Hans","age":3},{"name":"Ani","age":7},{"name":"Morgan","age":3},{"name":"Budi","age":10},{"name":"Lee","age":13}]
 
const studentsByAgeMap = students.reduce((m, o) => {
  m.has(o.age) || m.set(o.age, [])
  
  m.get(o.age).push(o)
  
  return m
}, new Map())

const result = studentsByAgeMap.get(Math.min(...studentsByAgeMap.keys()))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Lodash the above can be achieved in one line.

_.minBy(students, function(o) {return o.age})